# Naming of CDFs that do not attain 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

It might seem trivial but I keep asking myself whether there is a name for a cdf and its derivative that does not attain 1 in the limit, i.e. I‘m thinking of cases like

Let A, B, and C be the lifetime of some parts of a machine that are distributed iid on some support. The machine fails when 2 parts fail and the lifetime of the third part is then censored. Let G(x) be the observed distribution of lifetimes when A survives longest.

$$G(x)=\mathbb{P}[A>B,C \& B,C<x]$$

Clearly, when x goes to infinity, G(x) attains $1/3$. Is there a name for such distributions?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem setup is wrong. One of the *requirements* on cdf is that is attains 1 as its limit, otherwise it is not a cdf :-)

In your case, you likely want to define
$$
G(x) = \mathbb{P}\left[ \max\{B,C\} < x | A > \max\{B,C\}\right]
$$
in which case
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} G(x) = 1,
$$
as expected...

Comment: Thank you. Yes I know about that, I was reading a paper recently and they called the probability in the problem above a cdf, and I thought there might be another name for it I don’t know. The conditional probability suggested by you is perfectly fine :)

Comment: @nonparametrix including a reference to the paper in question with that explanation into your question would likely have avoided the downvote from whoever gave it...